# Flex 4 spark tabbar. How do I Reduce space between tabbar button and bordercontainer

Tags: flex4, tabbar

How do I remove the space between tab button and border container.

The code is

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{vsApplication}" >

 <s:layout>
  <!--<s:ButtonBarHorizontalLayout gap="7" />-->
  <s:HorizontalLayout gap="7" paddingBottom="0"/>
 </s:layout>

 </s:TabBar>

 <mx:ViewStack id="vsApplication" width="100%">

  <s:NavigatorContent id="ncConfiguration" label="Configuration" width="100%">
   <s:BorderContainer width="100%">

   </s:BorderContainer>
  </s:NavigatorContent>

  <s:NavigatorContent id="ncProject" label="Project" width="100%">
   <s:BorderContainer width="100%">
   <mx:DataGrid id="dgProject" dataProvider="{projectData}" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="dgProject_itemDoubleClickHandler(event)">
    <mx:columns>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Project ID" dataField="ProjectID"/>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Project Name" dataField="ProjectName"/>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Planned Start Date" dataField="PlannedStartDate"/>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Planned End Date" dataField="PlannedEndDate"/>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Actual Start Date" dataField="ActualStartDate"/>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Actual End Date" dataField="ActualEndDate"/>
    </mx:columns>
   </mx:DataGrid>
   </s:BorderContainer>
  </s:NavigatorContent>

  <s:NavigatorContent id="ncTimesheet" label="Timesheet" width="100%">
   <s:BorderContainer width="100%">

   </s:BorderContainer>
  </s:NavigatorContent >

  <s:NavigatorContent id="ncDashboard" label="Dashboard" width="100%">
   <s:BorderContainer width="100%">

   </s:BorderContainer>
  </s:NavigatorContent>

 </mx:ViewStack>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem - no padding or gap specified anywhere, but there was a space between the TabBar and the ViewStack.

The fix was to set `gap="0"` in the layout of the parent component (in my case a Panel with VerticalLayout).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by doing the same as Andy but just wrapping the components in another component

from

```
  <s:TabBar dataProvider="{viewStack}"/>
  <mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" width="100%" height="25%" creationPolicy="all">
    <view:TabA id="tabA"/>
    <view:TabB id="tabB"/>
  </mx:ViewStack>
```

to

```
<s:VGroup gap="0" width="100%">
  <s:TabBar dataProvider="{viewStack}"/>
  <mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" width="100%" height="25%" creationPolicy="all">
    <view:TabA id="tabA"/>
    <view:TabB id="tabB"/>
  </mx:ViewStack>
</s:VGroup>
```

In this case I wrapped my tab bar and view stack in a VGroup as I did not want to affect the gaps of any other component in my window.